# JS Browser Loading animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to stop browser load animation. I use hidden i frames and refresh them very often, and I don't want users to see annoying load animation and progress bar.

Comment: You can't prevent this unless you change your architecture, is AJAX an option?

Comment: @jAndy what, can't a man even nurse his bot net in peace without getting funny looks? :D

Comment: @Pekka: you're right, I apologize for my manners :) But to make things clear.@Coder_: `It's a big nono to do anything behind the scenes regardless for what purpose, without leeting an user know about what is going on.`

Comment: @jAndy: Ah, this sounds more clear to me, too. Though I understand your message and mostly agree with it, I can think of situations where you want these things to happen without annoying distractions for the user, e.g. auto-saving in a web application.

Comment: @Marcel @jAndy yup, I can thing of a number of legitimate uses for this, too, especially within a CMS or Web App the user is logged in to. Auto-Saving is one, or frequent polling the other. (Though the latter should really be done using Ajax.)

Comment: @jAndy - That's right, leet the user, improves their skill :)

Comment: @Nick: hehe, yaa l33t them! For glory and victory! @Pekka: You're right, there are cases where background workers make sense, but I don't see the need to hide all kinds of loading animations or progressbars.

Comment: No I was using AJAX and it was too slow, I'm writing a chat and refreshing iframes gave me a good speed. The only problem was that loading progress bar and a mouse pointer changing to hourglass in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Are you using long polling? If so it's probably a bug in the js library you are using.  this happen to me as well. Make sure you have the latest release of your libraries.